# cakephp3 - plugin class Table not load

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I make a plugin Blog with cakephp3.
When I call the url /blog/edit/3, all is good, the form inputs are filled.

I have a class \Blog\Model\Table\ArticlesTable (file location: ROOT/plugins/Blog/src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php)

Here the class :

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Model\Table;

use \Cake\ORM\Table;
use \Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
  public function initialize(array $config)
  {
    //die('IN ArticlesTable::initialize');
    $this->table('articles');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
  }

  public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

In the debugar, I see the message :

> Generated Models
>
> The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete
>   class: Articles

- I check namespace and the case of file
- I run command *composer dumpautoloader*

But my class is not loaded

Some one has an idea about my problem ?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: I guess you shouldn't use `use \Cake\ORM\Table;` but `use Cake\ORM\Table;`. I mean, remove the first slash. I'll recommend you to use bake to generate the base code.

Comment: I remove `Blog/src/Model/Entity/Article.php` and `Blog/Model/Entity/Article.php` and run the command :

`bin\cake.bat bake model Articles -p Blog`

Files are created but the problem persists :

**The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete class: Articles**

Comment: Where and how is the specific table instance created?

Comment: in the folder /plugins/Blog/src/Model/Table/ and the filename is ArticlesTable.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem. You need to specify the plugin namespace while loading the model:

```
$this->loadModel('Namespace.TableName');
```

In my example I changed:

```
class BlogController extends AppController
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadModel('Articles');//<----- HERE
  }
...
}
```

to

```
class BlogController extends AppController
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadModel('Blog.Articles'); //<----- HERE
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the `ArticlesTable` class in the `src/Model/Table` folder. The easiest way to do it is using the bake command

```
bin/cake bake model Articles
```

Comment: I run the command, files **\plugins\Blog\src\Model\Table\ArticlesTable.php**, **\plugins\Blog\src\Model\Entity\Article.php** are created but these files are not loaded.
I'm on Windows is it the reason ?! is there a cache to clean ?

Comment: Follow the instructions in this section: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes

Comment: In My /config/bootstrap.php, I have 
`Plugin::loadAll( 'Blog' => ['routes' => true, 'autoload' => true, ]);`
In the /composer.json
`"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src",
            "Blog\\": "./plugins/Blog/src"
        }
    },`
But the problem persits with the line _$this->loadModel('Blog.Articles');_ commented so the autload doesn't work